# InvalidOpearationException: There is already an open DataReader

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, winforms

Hello I create controls from SQL via this code:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM [schema] WHERE idSch=@id";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", result);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader read= com.ExecuteReader();

            while (read.Read())
            {

                createLabelCmd((int)read["x"], (int)read["y"]);


            }
            con.Close();
```

The issue is that `createLabelCmd` contains `SqlCommand` and it needs an open `SqlConnection`

Inside `createLabelCmd`

```
String ResultSitting
private void createLabelCmd(int x, int y)
    {
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            var newLabel = new Label();
            newLabel.Location = new Point(x, y);
            newLabel.Text = realpocsed.ToString();
            string sitting = newLabel.Name;
            string sittingSearch = (sitting).Substring(3, 1);
            if (sittingSearch != null && kzajezdu == "kZajezdu")
            {
                string querySitting = "SELECT name, surname FROM klient WHERE sitting = @sitting AND event=@event AND year=@year";
                SqlCommand cmdSitting = new SqlCommand(querySitting, spojeni);
                cmdSitting.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sitting", sittingSearch);
                cmdSitting.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event", idEvent);
                cmdSitting.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", klientClass.Year());

                ResultSitting = cmdSitting.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Trim(); //This might be the issue

            }

            if (kzajezdu == "kZajezdu")
            {
                newLabel.MouseHover += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    ToolTip ToolTip1 = new ToolTip();
                    ToolTip1.ShowAlways = true;
                    if (sittingSearch != null)
                    {
                        ToolTip1.Show(ResultSitting, newLabel);
                    }
                    else { ToolTip1.Show("This sitting is Empty!", newLabel); }
                };

            }

            panel1.Controls.Add(newLabel);
        }
```

I get an Exception: `InvalidOpearationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.`

May you please help me solve this out?

Edit as Soner Gönül suggested:

```
try
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM [schema] WHERE idSch=@id";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idSch);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader read= com.ExecuteReader();

            while (precti.Read())
            {
                createLabelCmd((int)read["x"], (int)read["y"]);

            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for that point. I hope it doesn`t effect the main issue with open DataReader.

Comment: I've deleted my comment since i've noticed that it indeed works to select multiple columns with `ExecuteScalar`. It seems that `SqlCommand` picks simply the first column. However, that isn't best practise at all.

Comment: on which line you are getting the error?

Comment: @Rezoan `createLabelCmd((int)read["x"], (int)read["y"]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the problem is outlined in other answers (while a DataReader is open, the connection used by that reader cannot serve other commands), however many fails to talk about [MultipleActiveResultSets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx) that has been introduced for this kind of situations

Just change your connection string to include this option and your code will work without any change

```
Server=yourServer;Database=yourDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

To complete the answer, MARS is available starting from SQL Server 2005 and [there are minor problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374444/disadvantages-of-mars-multiple-active-result-sets) that you should be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you while loop with your open `SqlDataReader`, there is an open connection already.

From [`DataReaders (ADO.NET)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254509.aspx)

> “You can use the ADO.NET DataReader to retrieve a read-only,
>   forward-only stream of data from a database.
>
> Results are returned as the query executes, and are stored in the
>   network buffer on the client until you request them using the Read
>   method of the DataReader”

As a general recomendation, use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) like;

```
using(SqlDataReader read= com.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (read.Read())
    {
       createLabelCmd((int)read["x"], (int)read["y"]);
    }
}
```

Or set this in your connection string;

```
...MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

Comment: I replaced the part of my code as you suggested (you can see in my edit) but still got the same Exception. May you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are writing a sitting planner and try to show labels at specific positions. Therefore, you would better select all records from `klient` table for a given event and put them in a `DataSet`. Then iterate through it (using a `foreach`) and create the labels. This way, there is only ONE command that should be sent to database and , obviously, the performance of your application will be much better.

Having said that, I don't understand how your `sittingSearch` variable work and I think it needs revising.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a 2nd connection for createLabelCmd or turn on MARS (multiple active results sets) in your initial connection by adding "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" to your connection string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Setting MARS to True AND
making sure i used ToList(); in my if statements and returns
in the below code i was missing the toList() in both conditions of the if statement, i was getting the error on IIS 8.5 after publishing .. updating the statement to the below worked@!

```
var varM = (id == 1) ? db.M.Where(x => x.UN== userID).ToList() : db.M.Where(x => x.EUN== userID).ToList();
```