# How to address Entity Framework Open DataReader Issue

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, database-connection, datareader

After getting this error :

> MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with
>   this Connection which must be closed first.

I was unable to request or get result sets because i was querying while EF was still lazy loading other stuff that i had previously requested.

Found many possible solutions to address this issue which i have shared as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mention the type [loading](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/eager-loading-lazy-loading-and-explicit-loading-in-entity-framework/) in EF configuration, EF will by default use Lazy Loading.

There are various ways to over come the 'Connection is open issue':

1. By adding [MARS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-multiple-active-result-sets-mars?view=sql-server-2017) to your EF connection string, please also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374444/disadvantages-of-mars-multiple-active-result-sets) before jumping into it.
2. Use '[USING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)' statement, but for this you need to create a new entity object every time it gets disposed.
3. Convert your result to Generics types or into local object types in my case i converted it ToList() which helped address my issue and i was able to request a new result set from the context.

I have a base class that provides me with the context object, which is why i didn't use **Using** statement to create new context every-time i wanted to query the context.

feel free to edit any mistakes, still learning about EF and its behavior.